# How can I create an Eclipse plugin that extends Java syntax coloring in certain files?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting

I am working with a system that uses regular Java code with snippets of a new code syntax inside of it. This system will compile regular java files, and these special files with a different extension. At the moment, these special files are edited with Eclipse's regular text editor. How can I add an editor that will use the regular Java syntax coloring with a small addition?

Comment: [This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEditors/article.html) should be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You should develop an Eclipse plugin extending from Eclipse Editor.

the comment of @Elist is right place to go.